# GET selected option to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to get the value of my selected option into my PHP so i can use it in a query.
However it keeps returning: `null`

My code:

```
<form onsubmit="getAlles()" method = "get">
    <select name="optionsDrop" id = "optionsDrop" class="buttons">

    </select>
    <input name="submitbutton" type="submit" value="submit" onclick = 'refresh()' />    
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
window.onload= function getAlles()
{
$.getJSON('js/getVoorraad.php', function (data) {
    refresh('#voorraadTable', data);
});

function refresh (tbBodyId, data) {
    var i, j;
    arrHTML = [];

    console.log(data);
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        arrHTML.push('<tr>');
        for (j= 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
            arrHTML.push('<td>' + data[i][j] + '</td>');
        }
        arrHTML.push('<td>' + "<input type = 'number' value = '1' min = '1' style=\"width: 40px;\" onKeyUp=\"this.style.width = Math.max(40,this.value.length*13)+'px';\"></input>" + '</td>');
        arrHTML.push('<td>' + "<button class='but' onClick = 'replyClick(this.id)'>Voeg toe</button>" + '</td>');
        arrHTML.push('</tr>');
    }
    $(tbBodyId).html(arrHTML.join(''));


}

}
```

The options are inserted from a database.
What i want to do is: select a option from the select box, which will then be given to PHP. Then i will insert the selected option into a WHERE statement in SQL.

PHP Code:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');

$selectedoption =  $_GET['optionsDrop'];

var_dump($_GET);
var_dump($selectedoption);

$accdbFilename = "C:\Users\Me/Proftaak DBB.accdb";
$connection = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=$accdbFilename", "", "");

$qFormat = <<<EOQ
select l.Naam, ac.catomschrijving, Aantal
from voorraad vo, locatie l, artikelcategorie ac
where vo.typeNr = ac.typeNr
and l.locatieNr = vo.locatieNr
and l.Naam = '%s'
EOQ;
var_dump($qFormat);

$query = sprintf($qFormat, $selectedoption);
var_dump($query);

$result = odbc_exec($connection, $query);

$rs = [];
for ($rownr = 0; odbc_fetch_row($result); $rownr++) {
    for($colnr = 1; $colnr <= odbc_num_fields($result); $colnr++) {
        $rs[$rownr][] = odbc_result($result, $colnr);
    }
}

echo json_encode($rs);
odbc_close($connection);
?>
```

However the it keeps saying:

> Undefined index: Undefined index: optionsDrop in
>   **C:\Users\Me\voorraadbeheer\js\getVoorraad.php** on line
>   **4**
>  array(0) { } NULL

How do i get the value, or text from the option in the select box. So i can use it?

Comment: check in your browser console like (firebug) what is going in GET. and when you are calling `refresh()` on onsubmit, why is it withut any parameters?

Comment: You are not passing any argument to your PHP script. That id why you are having this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong but isn't it just that you are not passing any data via the getJSON call? (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).

```
window.onload = function() 
{
    $("#optionsDrop").change(function() 
    {
        $.getJSON('js/getVoorraad.php', 
            {optionsDrop:$("#optionsDrop").val()},
            function (data) {
               refresh('#voorraadTable', data);
            }
        );
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the onSubmit="getAlles()" and put action="js/getVoorraad.php"